# Cannot login to django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I cannot login to django-admin with valid username and password. The problem started when I changed the db from sqlite to postgresql.

I tried to create new users through `./manage.py createsuperuser` but no change. From pgAdmin III I can see the users are created properly and `is_staff` and is_superuser flags are all true.

I am using Django 1.6 and I create my migrations through South.

Update: I edited the auth back-end to accept login via email. I use this script in another project too and works there. Let me know what you think.

**backend.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class EmailAuthenticationBackend(ModelBackend):
    """
    Authenticate against django.contrib.auth.models.User using
    e-mail address instead of username.
    """
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email__iexact = username)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

**settings.py**

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('project.apps.account.backend.EmailAuthenticationBackend', )
```

**Database Setting**

```
   DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': 'cloudapp',          
            'USER': 'clouduser',
            'PASSWORD': 'my_password',
            'HOST': 'localhost',
            'PORT': '',
        }
    }
```

Comment: you already ran python manage.py syncdb ?

Comment: Yes, did that but no change.

Comment: And your database conf is correct?

Comment: The db config is correct. running python manage.py shell I can query data to this database.

Comment: Do you have custom auth backends or have you replaced authentication backends?

Comment: Yes, I edited it to login using emails. Let me update the question with the details.

Comment: Updated the code with the auth backend I am using.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a good idea to replace all authentication backends with your own.
You can have several backends at the same time:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('project.apps.account.backend.EmailAuthenticationBackend', 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',)
```

So after that admin will have ability to log in with username/password and at your custom login page users will have ability to log in by email/password.

Comment: Replace that but does not work. Having 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend' alone does not work either

Comment: `ModelBackend` is the default by django. It's weird that when you left it alone it does not work. Did you do something else with authentication?

Comment: Nothing, strange it worked with sqlite, taking it back does not work any more. Tried to clear caches but still not working.

Comment: Configuration seems to be correct. You mentioned 'cloudapp'. At your local machine it doesn't works too?

Comment: Verified, the database setting is correct since it create the migration and the user table is filled well. Only the logins fails.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59221/discussion-between-coldmind-and-kiu-felix).